# Chrome/Firefox and Jetty HTTPS

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, ssl, jetty

I have an application running on Jetty 6 which is accessed over HTTPS. Connecting with IE 11 works but not Firefox 43 or Google 40.
The SSL trace shows that Jetty and browser fail to find a common cipher:

```
   %% Initialized:  [Session-13, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
   %% Invalidated:  [Session-13, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
   783842035@qtp-1833323686-4, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
   783842035@qtp-1833323686-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
   [Raw write]: length = 7
   0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
   783842035@qtp-1833323686-4, called closeSocket()
   783842035@qtp-1833323686-4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

However, when IE 11 is used the selected cipher is `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`:

```
    %% Initialized:  [Session-30, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
    %% Negotiating:  [Session-30, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
    *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
```

Since Chrome warns about RC4 ciphers when it fails to connect:

> > A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an >>unsupported protocol or cipher suite. This is likely to be caused when the >>server needs RC4, which is no longer considered secure.

I have excluded RC4 in java.security by adding the following property

```
    jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=RC4
```

but to no avail, Chrome and FF still fail to connect.
I've ran out of ideas. Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Check your server using a tool such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html to find what cipher suites are offered. Chances are Jetty 6 offers ciphers that are now deprecated for security reasons and no longer supported by newer versions of Firefox and Chrome (see the handshake simulation section of SSL Labs). I'm having a hard time finding references on how to supply additional cipher suites to Jetty 6.

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 6 is *long ago* EOL (End of Life).

If you stick with Jetty 6, know that the level of SSL/TLS tweaking you need is not present in that version of Jetty.

You'll either have to stick with JVM level tweaks, or write a custom `SslSelectChannelConnector` (sorry, the easier `SslContextFactory` concepts were introduced in Jetty 7) implementation of your own to accomplish the necessary includes and excludes of ciphers and protocols, along with the new TLS ciphers ordering requirements to pull this off reliably.

Jetty 9.3.7.v20160115 is [almost up to date with the recent and upcoming browser changes](https://bugs.eclipse.org/486877).  The next release, likely 9.3.8, will have the remaining tweaks necessary to support the recent browser changes, but only under Java 8u72 (or newer).

Also of note, since you have SSL/TLS enabled on Jetty, you have to keep your version of Java up to date, if for no other reason then to keep up with the changes in SSL/TLS over the past few years.